# JSON - Testing For No Value

Tags: java, json

Does anybody know what the syntax is to test a JSON object that returns no value? For example, if the user types in a wrong web address and the JSON code does not retrieve anything. Below, I first grab an array Object from the specific site that I'm using:

```
JSONArray hourlyForecast = jsonObj.getJSONArray("hourly_forecast");
```

But what if this doesnt retrieve anything. How can I test that? I tried

```
if(hourlyForecast==null){}
```

But it's not working because I'm not sure if that's a null object. My log cat returns this:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for error
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply try to catch the exception.

As per the [JavaDocs](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray(java.lang.String)):

> Throws:
>
> `JSONException` - if the key is not found or if the value is not a JSONArray.

This means that it throws an exception if the value is not found (if it's a null object).

So you can do:

```
try {
    JSONArray hourlyForecast = jsonObj.getJSONArray("hourly_forecast");
catch(JSONException e) {
    // what to do if empty JSON
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `jsonObject.has("key")` to check for existence of value.